# Connecting AzureDatabricks on a CosmosDB MongoDB API database

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, databricks, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to connect a Python notebook in an Azure Databricks cluster on a CosmosDB MongoDB API database.

I'm using the mongo connector 2.11.2.4.2
Python 3

My code is as follows:

```
ReadConfig = {
  "Endpoint" : "https://<my_name>.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:443/",
  "Masterkey" : "<my_key>",
  "Database" : "database",
  "preferredRegions" : "West US 2",
  "Collection": "collection1",
  "schema_samplesize" : "1000",
  "query_pagesize" : "200000",
  "query_custom" : "SELECT * FROM c"
}



df = spark.read.format("mongo").options(**ReadConfig).load()
df.createOrReplaceTempView("dfSQL")
```

The error I get is that Could not initialize class com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$.

How can I work this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my own question.

Using **MAVEN** as the source, I installed the right library to my cluster using the path

**org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.0**

**Spark 2.4**

An example of code I used is as follows (for those who wanna try):

```
# Read Configuration
readConfig = {
    "URI": "<URI>",
    "Database": "<database>",
    "Collection": "<collection>",
  "ReadingBatchSize" : "<batchSize>"
  }


pipelineAccounts = "{'$sort' : {'account_contact': 1}}"

# Connect via azure-cosmosdb-spark to create Spark DataFrame 
accountsTest = (spark.read.
                 format("com.mongodb.spark.sql").
                 options(**readConfig).
                 option("pipeline", pipelineAccounts).
                 load())

accountsTest.select("account_id").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you using latest Azure Cosmos DB Spark Connector.

1. Download the latest azure-cosmosdb-spark library for the version of Apache Spark you are running:

   Spark 2.4: azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11-2.1.2-uber.jar

   Spark 2.3: azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11-1.2.2-uber.jar

   Spark 2.2: azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.2.0_2.11-1.1.1-uber.jar
2. Upload the downloaded JAR files to Databricks following the instructions in Upload a Jar, Python Egg, or Python Wheel.
3. Install the uploaded libraries into your Databricks cluster.

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks - Azure Cosmos DB](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/cosmosdb-connector.html)

Comment: Those jars are for SQL API only.

Comment: Glad to you known, you are able to resolve the issue by installing the correct library.